# How to connect to a Cloud SQL instance in Netbeans

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Using Netbeans 7.3, I am trying to connect to my Cloud SQL instance. I have authorized the project on my local machine with gauth using python 2.7. I though this would create the OAuth 2.0 tokens needed but when I test the connection using "com.google.cloud.sql.Driver", the connection cannot be established. I plan to deploy the Java application on App Engine, using some kind of ORM againts the

Any suggestions what to do to make this connection work?

Comment: This [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database) describes how to connect your Java App Engine application to a Cloud SQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday : you must download and launch the Google Cloud SQL command line tool. It will allow you to authorize your Google account to access the cloud SQL service with OAuth2 authentication on your local machine.

Follow the steps described here : https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline

Once your application is deployed on App Engine, you will need to configure your database to allow your application to access it. That's pretty straightforward, see the Google APIs Console :https://code.google.com/apis/console/

**EDIT : You can now use a simple MySQL JDBC Connector and configure your Cloud SQL instance with a fixed IP. It means you can access your Cloud SQL instance from anywhere just like you would do for a classic MySQL databse.**

Comment: Thanks, but I have already done that. The authorization process works like a charm but neither Netbeans nor Eclipse can connect using the cloud sql driver in the App Engine SDK's impl folder.

Comment: I have tried all day. The Oauth2 authorization does not let Netbeans connect. I get a "unauthorized_client" message with a Http 400 when testing a connection to the database. I really don't know what to do now.

Comment: oh sorry it's not the exact same case, I was just testing OUTSIDE eclipse through command line maven appengine plugin...

Comment: Thanks though! I will give Amazon RDS a go instead :)